# Android Studio no detecta la función del OnClick

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

tengo un problema con un boton que he ubicado en un fragmento, quiero que al pulsarlo este te cambie la Activity principal a otra, tengo puesta la función adaptada al filtro (o eso creo), pero al probarla la app se apaga y en el "Run" me aparece el siguiente error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Cambio(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'btn_C_P_Filtros'`

El código XML del fragmento es el siguiente:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#861B8A"
    tools:context=".header_perfil">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Filtros"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="#00F66DD4"
        android:text="Perfil"
        android:textColor="#DAFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_C_P_Filtros"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:onClick="Cambio"
        android:text="Filtros"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y el código con la función para cambiar de Activity es este:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link header_perfil#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class header_perfil extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public header_perfil() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment header_perfil.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static header_perfil newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        header_perfil fragment = new header_perfil();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_perfil, container, false);
    }
    public void Cambio(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Filtros.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Algo que quiero añadir también es que en el código de java me dice que dicha función nunca se utiliza, cuando en el XML está seleccionada para que se ejecute cuando pulse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué no detecta la función?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código Java completo.

Answer (score 1):

Si defines el mètodo a llamar en tu layout:

```
 android:onClick="Cambio"
```

debes definirlo en tu còdigo el mètodo, recibiendo el parametro de la vista que lo llama:

```
public void Cambio(View v){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Con respecto a el error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Cambio(View) in
> a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on
> view class

Si estas en una Activity debes asegurar que el layout que carga esta activity mediante `setContentView()` es en verdad el que contiene la definiciòn de `android:onClick`. Si estas en un `Fragment`, asegura que la `Activity` en la cual esta contenida el `Fragment` es la misma que carga el layout que contiene la definiciòn de `android:onClick`

Comment: El XML que he definido es del Fragment que contiene el botón, no del Activity. Por ello, en el Java, utilizo la función ```getActivity()``` en vez de poner el ```this``` que ya está definido en la clase que se ha creado con el Fragment.